# SQL Server - JSON Handling Unknown First Element

Tags: json, sql-server

I am capturing JSON data from a number of services sources to a table in SQL Server; where it is queued for processing. Each of the data sources has a different initial element to identify the type. A fictional example is below.

I can query the content of the file easily enough using json_value (example below) or json_query. What I'm struggling to figure out is identifying which type of file i have in order to commence processing. The identifier is the name of first element "AddressDetails" in the example below. Is there a way in SQL's json querying to get the name of the first element out? Or do I need to push that up to the service that is receiving the data and save the type with the json data?

```
declare @test table (jsondata nvarchar(max))

insert into @test
select '{
    "AddressDetails": {
        "type": 1,
        "address": {
            "Street1": "A Street",
            "Street2": "",
            "town": "Bristol",
            "county": "Avon",
            "country": "England"
        }
}
} '


select 
json_value(jsondata, '$.AddressDetails."type"'),
json_value(jsondata, '$.AddressDetails.address."Street1"'),
json_value(jsondata, '$.AddressDetails.address."Street2"'),
json_value(jsondata, '$.AddressDetails.address."town"'),
json_value(jsondata, '$.AddressDetails.address."county"'),
json_value(jsondata, '$.AddressDetails.address."country"')
from @test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your structure will remain the same, except the first identifier 
you can use the following dynamic part:

***UPDATE***

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##Test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Test
    CREATE TABLE ##TEST (jsondata nvarchar(max))

    DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

    insert into ##TEST
    select '{
        "NameOfIdentifier": {
            "type": 1,
            "address": {
                "Street1": "A Street",
                "Street2": "",
                "town": "Bristol",
                "county": "Avon",
                "country": "England"
            }
        }
    }'


    SELECT @Cmd+= 'SELECT DISTINCT  '''+[Key]+''' as Identifier FROM ##TEST 
                CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsondata ,'''+'$.'+[Key]+''');' 
     FROM ##TEST
     CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON (jsondata )

     EXEC sp_executesql @Cmd
     DROP TABLE ##TEST
```

you'll get the following result:

[image: Identifier]

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for this; its not quite what im after in this instance the NameOfIdentifier field would be the one I need. That will help me identify the process for the data to run

Comment: So, in this example, if the query will return the name of the element "NameOfIdentifier" as a result set will that be what you need? if so, then a small modification is needed, let me know, and I'll change the script accordingly

Comment: Changed the script, It should be what you need now

Comment: I had hoped for an internal command for it; but this works just fine. Many Thanks